# Box-shadow with different size per side

Tags: css

I am currently working on basing a design, in which the designer has used a shadow on a div.
Since I am not fond of using images for this sort of thing, I have decided to take my CSS skills to the next level. I am completely new to CSS3, yet I want to give this a try using box-shadow. I have been reading into this new feature but I cannot seem to get my exact design working.

This is what I am searching for:

[image]

Top: 1px; 
Right: 5px; 
Bottom: 9px; 
Left: 5px

The designer has used different spreads (well, I believe it's called spreads in this context) for the shadow. My issue is that I cannot manage to get this working with different spreads per side of the div, can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

```
div {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intention of box-shadow is to create a shadow of the div you are assigning it to. You can't make specific top-left-right-bottom parts bigger or smaller

See: http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/

The only way this can be done is to fiddle with the variables

For example:

```
box-shadow: 0px 9px 15px 5px #888888;
```

This box-shadow will generate a box-shadow that..

- [0px] doesn't shift left or right
- [9px] is 9px down
- [15px] has 15px of blur (play around with it for the desired effect)
- [5px] is 5px wide (on all sides)
- [#888888] has a grey color

Another way would be to use border-images.

Comment: Hmm, what I thought. I had hoped it would be possible in some way that I hadn't read about. Thanks for the effort, I'll consider using a cheat like `box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px #000;` to come close to what the designer had in mind, or to use images.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty close: http://jsfiddle.net/EG6FA/

```
div {
    ...
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px #777;
}​
```

Comment: 0px 4px 5px is the exact value I am looking for. Due to the zero, left and right will be the defined 5. Top will be 5 minus 4 is 1 and bottom will be 5 plus 4 is 9. Though, this would mean that the first 4 pixels of the bottom are not 'fading'. But this results in a nice visual outcome.

Comment: The paramaters are `box-shadow:<x-offset> <y-offset> <blur-radius> <spread> <color>;` So if you do, say `box-shadow:0 4px 0 5px #777` You will have a solid box representing the bounds of the shadow you want. You can then play with the blur-radius to get the look you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px #888888;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px #888888;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px #888888;
```

(IE9 and IE10 will render a smaller box-shadow. Earlier Explorer versions will show no shadow.)